# Why the result is not as expected with flag "-race"?

Tags: go

Why the result is not as expected with flag "-race" ?
It expected the same result: 1000000 - with flag "-race" and without this

https://gist.github.com/romanitalian/f403ceb6e492eaf6ba953cf67d5a22ff

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

//$ go run -race main_atomic.go
//954203
//
//$ go run main_atomic.go
//1000000

type atomicCounter struct {
    val int64
}

func (c *atomicCounter) Add(x int64) {
    atomic.AddInt64(&c.val, x)
    runtime.Gosched()
}

func (c *atomicCounter) Value() int64 {
    return atomic.LoadInt64(&c.val)
}

func main() {
    counter := atomicCounter{}

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func(no int) {
            for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
                counter.Add(1)
            }
        }(i)
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(counter.Value())
}
```

Comment: You're not coordinating the goroutines in any way, so they are actually never guaranteed to run at all. Does it return the correct value if you add a proper WaitGroup and wait for them to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the result is not the same is because `time.Sleep(time.Second)` does not guarantee that all of your goroutines are going to be executed in the timespan of one second. Even if you execute `go run main.go`, it's not guaranteed that you will get the same result every time. You can test this out if you put `time.Milisecond` instead of `time.Second`, you will see much more inconsistent results.

Whatever value you put in the `time.Sleep` method, it does not guarantee that all of your goroutines will be executed, it just means that it's less likely that all of your goroutines won't finish in time.

For consistent results, you would want to synchronise your goroutines a bit. You can use `WaitGroup` or channels.

With `WaitGroup`:

```
//rest of the code above is the same
func main() {
    counter := atomicCounter{}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(no int) {
            for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
                counter.Add(1)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(counter.Value())
}
```

With channels:

```
func main() {
    valStream := make(chan int)
    doneStream := make(chan int)
    result := 0
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func() {
            for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
                valStream <- 1
            }
            doneStream <- 1
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        counter := 0
        for count := range doneStream {
            counter += count
            if counter == 100 {
                close(doneStream)
            }
        }
        close(valStream)
    }()

    for val := range valStream {
        result += val
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: With `Waitgroup`:
https://gist.github.com/romanitalian/41f727e3d1313055c44fbb01120b3119